Create unique ID for two tables and color cells if deference's were find VBA
in VBA I would like to compare two tables in one workbook and mark on color cells where i have difference's. First table is start in cell A1 and can have dynamic numbers of rows. Second table start 3 rows below in column B and also can be dynamic. I would like to color column F and H in second table if i have difference's.

I will be very grateful for the help. Is there a way to avoid using formulas in the code? And build better disctionary?
Sub test() 

    Dim LastRowLoC As Long
    Dim LastRowLoC1 As Long
    Dim ws_LoC As Worksheet
    Set ws_LoC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List of companies")
    LastRowLoC = ws_LoC.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowLoC1 = ws_LoC.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List of companies").Range("Y2:Y" & LastRowLoC).formula = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-23],""#"",RC[-19],""#"",RC[-17])"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List of companies").Range("N22:N" & LastRowLoC1).formula = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-12],""#"",RC[-8],""#"",RC[-6])"


Dim MyDictionary As New Dictionary
Dim key As String

For i = 2 To LastRowLoC
    MyDictionary.Add ws_LoC.Cells(i, 25).Text, ws_LoC.Cells(i, 2).Text
Next i

LastRowLoC1 = ws_LoC.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 22 To LastRowLoC1
    key = ws_LoC.Cells(i, 14).Value
    If MyDictionary.Exists(key) Then
        ws_LoC.Cells(i, 15) = ""
    Else
        ws_LoC.Cells(i, 15) = "Incorrect Codding"
    End If
Next i

For i = LastRowLoC1 To 22 Step -1
    If ws_LoC.Cells(i, 15).Value = "Incorrect Codding" Then
    'ws_LoC.Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    ws_LoC.Cells(i, 15).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
Next i

End Sub

